# save file into application folder using setDownloadDestinationPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, save, ios-simulator

I have the following code:

```
-(IBAction)downloadButton:(id)sender{

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://93.185.34.100/prob/pic1.zip"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];

//    NSString *pathString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/theZip.zip", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSString *filePath = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theZip"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] error:nil ]);
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
    NSLog(@"Value: %f", [progressView progress]*100);
    [request startAsynchronous];


}
```

It should download and store downloaded zip file into document directory. It does when I run it on simulator but doesn't work on device.

What is the problem?

Comment: you mention device and simulator: if this is an iOS/iPhone question then you should add those tags to get some more attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have is getting the path to the bundle directory.  Those are the resources that you include with your app.  Those resources can be **read**, but you cannot **write** or **change** them, once the app is installed.  Essentially, it's a read-only directory for your app.

If you want to save files, you should copy them (or save them) to the app's **Documents**, **Caches**, or **Application Support** folder.  You can get the paths to Documents and Caches folders with

```objc
NSArray* documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDir = (NSString*)[documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

and

```objc
NSArray* cachesPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* cachesDir = (NSString*)[cachesPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

[Here is an Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html) on saving files in iOS apps (search that page for **Determining Where to Save Your App-Specific Files**).  This will give some info about which directory is most applicable for this kind of data.

The important thing is that you use one of those folders, and not the read-only bundle folder.

Comment: your answer helped me a lot, Thanks. But can you edit it and put the link of where to save files in iPhone app? Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much...Solved the problem with saving on the device...Although still have the problem with reading saved image using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myJPG.jpg"];`

Comment: @Garnik, that code will only load an image named "myJPG.jpg" if it was part of the app's original resource bundle.  if you save an image in the documents or caches folders, you will have to use the full path to open it again.

Comment: yeap. I do it `NSString *photo=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"049.JPG"];` here. It returns me full path of the image, but it seems something goes wrong because there is no image in imageView.. :(

Comment: @Garnik, you should probably post a new question, with more of your code.  that's really a different problem than the one you asked about above.  thanks

Comment: yeap...Thanks a lot for your help...I just solved my problem...The problem