# How to create folder in Application folder

Tags: ios, directory, nsfilemanager

Is it possible to create a folder in this path?
`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application`

I am using below code but result always `NO`

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[@"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testFolderName"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]
```

Comment: No this directory is out side of your apps sandbox and therefor unaccessible.

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: I am saving my DB in the sandbox directory but after App update sandbox's path changes. And saved info becomes useless. Then where to save the info?

Answer (score 1):

You must save your db in the documents directory and retrieve it from there. iOS memory management will always know from where to get your DB even if the path changes.

Check this: [save file into application folder using setDownloadDestinationPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602706/save-file-into-application-folder-using-setdownloaddestinationpat)

For development purposes you might wanna log your DB path. Just add the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", YOURDBNAME.DB]];
```

Don't forget to add the extension to the file.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to have sandbox path change from OS? 
Sometimes this part changes `6BF0B7C0-AE59-42A8-ACAC-2A58D01A6737`

`file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ 6BF0B7C0-AE59-42A8-ACAC-2A58D01A6737/data/Containers/Data/Application/FA34448C-161D-4591-81C2-7BA807A21928/Documents/`